# Reconstruct My Matryoshka Dolls

Tags: code-golf, string

## Background

A [*matryoshka doll*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll) (or Russian nesting doll) is a set of dolls that fit inside of each other. I've accidentally mixed up my collection of matryoshka dolls and I don't remember which one goes inside which.

## Objective

Given a list of *unique* strings, sort them into nested matryoshka dolls. Each string is an individual doll, and a matryoshka doll is a list of strings.

## Rules

Let `min(a,b)` be the lexicographic min of strings `a` and `b`. Let `a ⊂ b` denote that `a` is a substring of `b`. Then,

1. The list of matryoshka dolls must be sorted lexicographically
2. String `a` can *fit* into string `b` if `a ⊂ b`
3. If `a ⊂ b` and `a ⊂ c`, then `a` will go inside `min(b,c)`
4. If both `a ⊂ c` and `b ⊂ c`, but `a ⊄ b` `b ⊄ a`, then only `min(a,b)` will go inside `c`
5. If both `a ⊂ c` and `b ⊂ c`, and also `a ⊂ b`, then only `b` will go inside `c`. I.e., superstrings go before substrings so that the matryoshka isn't prematurely terminated.

## Examples

```
In:
hahaha, hah, lol, lololol, bahaha, bah, haha, ah

Out:
bahaha, bah, ah
hahaha, haha, hah
lololol, lol

In:
aa, aaaa, a, aaaaaaaaaa

Out:
aaaaaaaaaa, aaaa, aa, a
```

Comment: First post here, please point out anything dumb / fixes needed.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If you're not sure if the post is good enough, you can post it in the Sandbox first.

Comment: @user202729, oh I just saw that. Can I move this into sandbox or do I have to delete / add proposal?

Comment: It's not mandatory, just keep it here. The community like it.

Comment: @sujeet in the future, try to post to the sandbox first. It's a place to get feedback about your challenges before you post them on the main site.  Don't worry about it now, since this challenge seems fine as is, but it's something to consider for the future.

Comment: This is a very nice challenge, but it could use a few more test cases.

Comment: @Dennis, thanks. I've added another test case. How many do you think I should list?

Comment: @sujeet do we need to delimit the matryoshka dolls or can we just return a list of strings? The dolls' positions should be unambiguous without delimiters

Comment: @dylnan list of strings is fine — as you say, you can always tell when a new matryoshka begins

Comment: What should be the result of `ab, ba, aba, bab`? By rule 3, both `ab` and `ba` should go into `aba`, and by rule 4, `ba` cannot go into either `aba` or `bab`.

Comment: I'm surprised rule 4 doesn't say that `max(a,b)` goes inside `c`...

Comment: @Zgarb, it should be `aba, ab` and `bab, ba`. I agree that the wording of rule 3/4 imply that if they are rejected from both they are just rejected. I did intend for them to be "recirculated".

Comment: I suggest that you add some more test cases. For example `abc, a, bc`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 298 bytes

```python
def f(x,E=enumerate):
 o=[]
 while any(x):
	for k,p in E(x):
	 e=0
	 if sum(i(p,j)for j in x)<1:
		for d,r in E(o):
		 if i(p,r[-1])*((r[-1]<e)or e==0):m,e=d,r[-1]
		if e:o[m]+=[p]
		else:o+=[[p]]
		x[k]=''
 print sorted(o)
i=lambda p,b:(b!=p)*any([p==b[j:j+len(p)]for j in range(len(b)-len(p)+1)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/djoMgEIWv16eYzV4ILU3avTTlsk9BvIA6ViwCQZu1T@8O2jYkzDlnvuEnPqcu@N/lB3yYEMYpWX@D81vYERzO9hpuScfOXrVbGmyhZbO4SPSPAZOekFcFBKnqAv466xC0f7KZwq82JLiLCNbDZUsA5ZF228L4GJhlUfQ8U31mZn4@EbOONSJtYyGPrROZTupwqvmOsVWckROKUh55NQiUzdYnnnCsghrqvVQxB@hGCsiRzX5W91qWZQGRPjrBGNKEDV1WWOn0YBoNUZiKmW8Z@S5/SEUpjeqrfu/Qs8jrz7OT9jdkOTX8sDX3J17zpWWq7HRepYCscnHBvUp4SfNBzIa8LTk65R8)

*-28 bytes with tips from @dylnan, bug find by @Dennis, and bug fix by @Mr.Xcoder*

Comment: [301 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/djoMgEIWvt08xzV4IlSbtXhp5EuIF1LFiEQjarH16d6htkw0Jc87Md/iJj7kP/mf9Bh9mhGlO1l@hfgs7gcPFXsI16djbi3Zrix10bBFBqoZXO/jtrUPQ/sEWsl9dSHATEawH9PcRk55xmwDKE@22g@k@MsuiGHimh8wuvD4T84y3Iv2Phxx/JnMqqeO54QfGnqJGThGU8sSrUaBstznxhGMV1NiUUsXcQDdRgxzZ7Bd1a2RR7CDSX2eYQpqxpct2Vjo9mlZDFKZiZi8jP@QPqiilUUM1lA49i7z5PD9pf0WWu4Yft2F55g1fO6aKXudVCMgqFxfcq4SXNB/EbMjbkqNT/gA). Just turned `i` into a lambda function and changed the variable name `out` to `o`.

Comment: [297 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY/djoMgEIWv16eYzV4ILU3avTRy2acgXkAdKxaBoM3ap@8O2jYkzDkz3@EnPuY@@N/nD/gwI0xzsv4K9VvYCRwu9hKuScfeXrR7tthBxxYRpGrEWaK/j5j0jLwq4K@3DkH7B1vIfnUhwU1EsB7OWwdQHmm3HUz3kVkWxcAzNWRm4fWJmDXWirTFQo6tiUwndTg1fMfYKmrkhKKUR16NAmW7zYknHKugxmYvVcwNdBM1yJHNflG3RpZlAZH@OcMU0owtXVZY6fRoWg1RmIqZbxn5Ln9IRSmNGqph79CzyJvPs5P2V2S5a/hhG@5PvOHPjqmy13mVArLKxQX3KuElzQcxG/K25OiUfw) (E=enumerate)

Comment: [Functions have to be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/12012), but the `out` variable never changes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU/LboMwEDyXr9iqB@yGSEmPKP4SiwOEJZgY2zJGJV9Pd6GJ1HtlybszO7OP8Ei9d1/rBzifEKYUjbvB5ZmYCSwu5upvsQ69udZ2bbGDTiyFn5PSlSwz@O6NRajdQywE3zof4V4EMA7QzSPGOuFeAVQn@k0H0zwKI0IxSFYPrF3k5Uyazd4W8a@dhnGDzcu@qI/nSn4KsSUXlGRCpU6yHAtU7V4nPcmxJLMeq4PSgSm000YRJoKZRd8rlecZBLo5weRjwnYbmfGxPK/hO1@rxtrdUFh0opFHDkEezrwfjWv0UA6HnayUCmXENEdSvqsgM9gRnNZO6Lyv@eUFcMbBevsb/G/avCTNLnlCQpXM/qXL@gM "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: To fix that issue, [298 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY/djoMgEIWv16eYzV4ILU3avTTlsk9BvIA6ViwCQZu1T@8O2jYkzDlnvuEnPqcu@N/lB3yYEMYpWX@D81vYERzO9hpuScfOXrVbGmyhZbO4SPSPAZOekFcFBKnqAv466xC0f7KZwq82JLiLCNbDZUsA5ZF228L4GJhlUfQ8U31mZn4@EbOONSJtYyGPrROZTupwqvmOsVWckROKUh55NQiUzdYnnnCsghrqvVQxB@hGCsiRzX5W91qWZQGRPjrBGNKEDV1WWOn0YBoNUZiKmW8Z@S5/SEUpjeqrfu/Qs8jrz7OT9jdkOTX8sDX3J17zpWWq7HRepYCscnHBvUp4SfNBzIa8LTk65R8). Also, `out`, 3-char variable name... Seriously :P?